# Wait for stateChange in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-mocha

I have a scope function in my controller with some async functions. After everything is done it changes the state.

controller.js

```
$scope.test = function () {
    async().then(function () {
        $state.go('somewhere');
    });
};
```

I could test it with `setTimeout()` but thats dirty I think.

How do I wait for the stateChange in my test?

**Edit:**

I want to write unit tests for the `test()` function but as it is no promise I need to watch for the state change in the test. But how? It works with `setTimeout()` but I don't want to use `setTimeout()` because it just doesn't feel right. Is there something like `$scope.$watch` for states?

test.js

```
...

it('test()', function (done) {
    $scope.test();
    setTimeout(function () { // I want this replaced with a listener for state
        expect($scope.someVar).to.be.equal('value');
        expect($state.current.name).to.be.equal('somewhere');
    });
});

...
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to know how to wait after all your async functions to execute so you can change the state, or detect when the state finished changing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was editing the question to describe my problem I found the solution.
It's possible to listen for broadcasted events so it's possible to use

```
...

it('test()', function (done) {
    $scope.test();
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        expect($scope.someVar).to.be.equal('value');
        expect(toState.name).to.be.equal('somewhere');
    });
});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`$q.all.(promises).then(
function(){
    $state.go()
});`

To wait for your tasks to finish, as long as you can wrap them in a promise.

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/q).